# EF Core, One to One relation - how to prevent overriding existing relation?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-one

I have the following sample:
2 Entities Store & Product

Data:

Stores:
Store1, Store2 Store3

Products:
Product1, Product2, Product3

Relations:
Store1 - Product1

The issue:
When selecting Product2 to connect it with Store1 than it will be connected automatically, the result will be:
Store1 - Product2

I would like to prevent this and want to see an exception (or anything else) if it happens.

There are thousands of stores and products in my db and I wouldn't like to filter the Product selection in code.

The DbContext OnModelCreating is:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Product)
                .WithOne() 
                .HasForeignKey<Store>(s => s.ProductId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: What do you mean of `connect it` here? I suggest that you provide us with the code for the execution of the issue, otherwise we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can't send code it's private and not necessary I think. It supposed to be a very common scenario. Connection means -> relation. Briefly a simple model is: Store { int Id, string Name, int? ProductId, virtual Product Product }.. When the Product is 'connected' via the ProductId for 1 Store and I connect it with another store, it automatically removes the relation from the first Store. This is my main issue. (By the way meanwhile I solved it in a different way, but still interested)